# Remove table if it has a row with "NA" values

Tags: javascript, html

I've HTML code like this`

```
<h4 id="dd">Resource usage</h4>
        <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>peak_value</th>
      <th>resource_name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm fetching the table from database.So, the data is dynamically created.
Now I don't want to show table if it has entire row with only "NA" values (i.e).,  value NA using javascript.
Please help me out here

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve that ? Show us some code.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to hide the whole table if it has at least one row that has only "NA" values even if other rows have non-"NA" values? Or do you mean that it should only be hidden if *every* row has only "NA" values?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `td` elements and see if there is any element with a non `NA` value, if not hide the table like

```js
var table = document.querySelector('#dd + table');
var toShow = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('td')).some(td => td.innerHTML.trim() != 'NA');;
if (!toShow) {
  table.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<h4 id="dd">Resource usage</h4>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>peak_value</th>
      <th>resource_name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k8uj6q0v/1/)

---

If you want to handle row wise

```js
var table = document.querySelector('#dd + table');

var tableHasNonNAValue = false;
Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach(tr => {
  var hasNonNAValue = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td')).some(td => td.innerHTML.trim() != 'NA');
  tableHasNonNAValue = tableHasNonNAValue || hasNonNAValue;
  if (!hasNonNAValue) {
    tr.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
if (!tableHasNonNAValue) {
  table.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<h4 id="dd">Resource usage</h4>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>peak_value</th>
      <th>resource_name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NA1</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k8uj6q0v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `jQuery.filter` to filter all `td` elements having text as `"NA"`
- Check length of the filtered collection with length of the `td` elements in respective `tr` element
- If `tr` had `td` elements and length is equal, `hide()` the `tr` element.

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var tdElems = $(this).find('td');
  var filtered = tdElems.filter(function() {
    return this.textContent.trim() === 'NA';
  });
  if (tdElems.length && (filtered.length === tdElems.length)) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="dd">Resource usage</h4>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>peak_value</th>
      <th>resource_name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```